# Pytorch: Combining Automatic and Manual Methods

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

I am testing a two-step architecture that is composed of a conventional first section that can be implemented with any standard deep learning architecture and a second section that must be coded manually outside the declaration of the Pytorch graph (while still utilizing numpy-like torch functions).

My problem can be simplified to coding a feed-forward neural network with two hidden layers, where the first is implemented within the Pytorch graph and the second is implemented manually outside the Pytorch graph.

**Architecture:**

```
Input
-> Linear(28 * 28, 120) w/ Pytorch 
-> ReLU w/ Pytorch 
-> Linear(120, 84) w/ Pytorch 
-> ReLU w/ Pytorch 
-> Linear(84, 10) w/o Pytorch 
-> Output
```

**Problem:** My implementation below achieves a very low ~74%, while a standard fully Pytorch implementation achieves ~95%. What is causing this disparity?

I believe my problem lies in manually passing back the deltas, although the math looks right, so I am stuck in finding a solution to this.

**Implementation** of architecture and training on MNIST:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return x

net = Net()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# Initialize weights just as Pytorch does by default:
m = torch.distributions.uniform.Uniform(torch.tensor([-np.sqrt(1.0/84)]),
                                        torch.tensor([np.sqrt(1.0/84)]))
W = m.sample((84, 10)).reshape((84, 10))

# based on https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html
for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs
        inputs, labels = data

        # make one-hot encoding of labels
        targets = oneHot(labels)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        pytorch_outputs = net(inputs)
        pytorch_outputs = torch.autograd.Variable(pytorch_outputs,
                                                  requires_grad=True)

        manual_outputs = torch.mm(pytorch_outputs, W)

        delta_out = manual_outputs - targets.view(-1,10)  # = error_out 
        dEdW3 = torch.mm(torch.t(pytorch_outputs), delta_out)
        W -= 0.01 * dEdW3  # gradient descent

        delta_h = torch.autograd.Variable(
                                  torch.t(torch.mm(W, torch.t(delta_out))))

        loss = criterion(pytorch_outputs, delta_h)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

**Full code:**

```py
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True,
                                     download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=1,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=1)

testset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False,
                                     download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=1,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=1)

classes = ('0', '1', '2', '3',
           '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')

def oneHot(a):
    b = torch.zeros(10)
    b[a] = 1
    return b

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return x

net = Net()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# Initialize weights just as Pytorch does by default:
m = torch.distributions.uniform.Uniform(torch.tensor([-np.sqrt(1.0/84)]),
                                        torch.tensor([np.sqrt(1.0/84)]))
W = m.sample((84, 10)).reshape((84, 10))

# based on https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html
for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs
        inputs, labels = data

        # make one-hot encoding of labels
        targets = oneHot(labels)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        pytorch_outputs = net(inputs)
        pytorch_outputs = torch.autograd.Variable(pytorch_outputs,
                                                  requires_grad=True)

        manual_outputs = torch.mm(pytorch_outputs, W)

        delta_out = manual_outputs - targets.view(-1,10)  # = error_out 
        dEdW3 = torch.mm(torch.t(pytorch_outputs), delta_out)
        W -= 0.001*dEdW3  # gradient descent

        delta_h = torch.autograd.Variable(
                                  torch.t(torch.mm(W, torch.t(delta_out))))

        loss = criterion(pytorch_outputs, delta_h)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

correct = 0
total = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in testloader:
        inputs, labels = data
        pytorch_outputs = torch.autograd.Variable(net(inputs), 
                                                      requires_grad=True)
        manual_outputs = torch.mm(pytorch_outputs, W)
        _, predicted = torch.max(manual_outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: %d %%' % (
    100 * correct / total))
```